# Pyaudio erro while creating apk using buildozer

Tags: python, kivy, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to generate an apk of an kivymd project But I'm getting an error about pyaudio when using the command "buildozer -v android debug" to build the apk.

I'm using google colab to run my buildozer.spec, and if I remove the pyaudio of requirements it works and generate an apk, but my project really needs the pyaudio module.

```
[DEBUG]:      In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.h:7:
[DEBUG]:      In file included from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/Python.h:11:
[DEBUG]:      /usr/include/limits.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
[DEBUG]:      #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
[DEBUG]:               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[DEBUG]:      1 error generated.
[DEBUG]:      error: command '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
[DEBUG]:      error: subprocess-exited-with-error
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:      × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
[DEBUG]:      │ exit code: 1
[DEBUG]:      ╰─> See above for output.
[DEBUG]:    
[DEBUG]:      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
[DEBUG]:      full command: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/bin/python /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpti037vst
[DEBUG]:      cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pvgejq6s/pyaudio_8ae6d81fa6c04d98be09bbc8811dcc80
[DEBUG]:      Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
[DEBUG]:      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
[DEBUG]:    Failed to build pyaudio
[DEBUG]:    ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
Exception in thread background thread for pid 93492:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 1641, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2569, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 2269, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install -v --target '"'"'/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a'"'"' --no-deps -r requirements.txt'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
Using pip 23.0.1 from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.7.0.72-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (61.8 MB)
Collecting paho-mqtt
  Using cached paho-mqtt-1.6.1.tar.gz (99 kB)
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching 'epl-v10'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  Using pip 23.0.1 from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
  Collecting setuptools<=65.1.1
    Using cached setuptools-65.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
    Creating /tmp/pip-build-env-g31od1on/overlay/bin
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-g31od1on/overlay/bin/wheel to 755
  Successfully installed setuptools-65.1.1 wheel-0.38.4
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running egg_info
  writing src/PyAudio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/PyAudio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/PyAudio.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/PyAudio.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/__pycache__'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/.mypy_cache'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running dist_info
  creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/__pycache__'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/.mypy_cache'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio-0.2.13.dist-info'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running command Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml)
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
  copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
  running build_ext
  building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio
  /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -I/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/include/python3.9 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
  In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.c:1:
  In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.h:7:
  In file included from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/Python.h:11:
  /usr/include/limits.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
  #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/bin/python /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpti037vst
  cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pvgejq6s/pyaudio_8ae6d81fa6c04d98be09bbc8811dcc80
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


  STDERR:

[DEBUG]:    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1312, in <module>
    main()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 734, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 212, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 528, in build_recipes
    run_pymodules_install(
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 757, in run_pymodules_install
    shprint(sh.bash, '-c', (
  File "/content/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 915, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 845, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sh.py", line 869, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /usr/bin/bash -c 'venv/bin/pip install -v --target '"'"'/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a'"'"' --no-deps -r requirements.txt'

  STDOUT:
Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
Using pip 23.0.1 from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv_python-4.7.0.72-cp37-abi3-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (61.8 MB)
Collecting paho-mqtt
  Using cached paho-mqtt-1.6.1.tar.gz (99 kB)
  Running command python setup.py egg_info
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running egg_info
  creating /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no files found matching 'epl-v10'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-6dym4vrg/paho_mqtt.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting pyaudio
  Using cached PyAudio-0.2.13.tar.gz (46 kB)
  Running command pip subprocess to install build dependencies
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  Using pip 23.0.1 from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip (python 3.9)
  Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
  Collecting setuptools<=65.1.1
    Using cached setuptools-65.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.38.4-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
  Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools
    Creating /tmp/pip-build-env-g31od1on/overlay/bin
    changing mode of /tmp/pip-build-env-g31od1on/overlay/bin/wheel to 755
  Successfully installed setuptools-65.1.1 wheel-0.38.4
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Running command Getting requirements to build wheel
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running egg_info
  writing src/PyAudio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to src/PyAudio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to src/PyAudio.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to src/PyAudio.egg-info/top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/__pycache__'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/.mypy_cache'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file 'src/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Running command Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml)
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running dist_info
  creating /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info
  writing /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing requirements to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/requires.txt
  writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/__pycache__'
  no previously-included directories found matching '**/.mypy_cache'
  adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
  writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  creating '/tmp/pip-modern-metadata-h3ea6s8h/PyAudio-0.2.13.dist-info'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pyaudio
  Running command Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml)
  Ignoring "sys._home = value" override
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
  copying src/pyaudio/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
  running build_ext
  building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio
  /root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -target aarch64-linux-android21 -fomit-frame-pointer -march=armv8-a -fPIC -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include -DANDROID -I/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot/usr/include -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/myapp/arm64-v8a/include/python3.9 -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.9 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
  In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.c:1:
  In file included from src/pyaudio/device_api.h:7:
  In file included from /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/python3/arm64-v8a__ndk_target_21/python3/Include/Python.h:11:
  /usr/include/limits.h:26:10: fatal error: 'bits/libc-header-start.h' file not found
  #include <bits/libc-header-start.h>
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  error: command '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/clang' failed with exit code 1
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/bin/python /content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py build_wheel /tmp/tmpti037vst
  cwd: /tmp/pip-install-pvgejq6s/pyaudio_8ae6d81fa6c04d98be09bbc8811dcc80
  Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio
Failed to build pyaudio
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


  STDERR:

# Command failed: ['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,paho-mqtt,opencv-python,pyaudio', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/content/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug']
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES = 'all'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_TRANSPORT = 'ipc'
#     NV_NVML_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcudnn8'
#     CGROUP_MEMORY_EVENTS = '/sys/fs/cgroup/memory.events /var/colab/cgroup/jupyter-children/memory.events'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnccl-dev=2.16.2-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     VM_GCE_METADATA_HOST = '169.254.169.253'
#     HOSTNAME = 'a68b405fbfba'
#     TBE_RUNTIME_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8011'
#     GCE_METADATA_TIMEOUT = '3'
#     NVIDIA_REQUIRE_CUDA = ('cuda>=11.8 brand=tesla,driver>=450,driver<451 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=unknown,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=geforcertx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=quadrortx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=470,driver<471 brand=titanrtx,driver>=470,driver<471 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=unknown,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=geforcertx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=quadrortx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=510,driver<511 brand=titanrtx,driver>=510,driver<511 '
 'brand=tesla,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=unknown,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=nvidia,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=nvidiartx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=geforce,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=geforcertx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=quadro,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=quadrortx,driver>=515,driver<516 '
 'brand=titan,driver>=515,driver<516 brand=titanrtx,driver>=515,driver<516')
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-dev-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     NV_NVTX_VERSION = '11.8.86-1'
#     COLAB_JUPYTER_IP = '172.28.0.12'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     NCCL_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     KMP_LISTEN_PORT = '6000'
#     TF_FORCE_GPU_ALLOW_GROWTH = 'true'
#     ENV = '/root/.bashrc'
#     PWD = '/content'
#     TBE_EPHEM_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8009'
#     TBE_CREDS_ADDR = '172.28.0.1:8008'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE = 'libcudnn8=8.7.0.84-1+cuda11.8'
#     NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES = 'compute,utility'
#     LAST_FORCED_REBUILD = '20230216'
#     NV_NVPROF_DEV_PACKAGE = 'cuda-nvprof-11-8=11.8.87-1'
#     NV_LIBNPP_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl-dev'
#     TCLLIBPATH = '/usr/share/tcltk/tcllib1.20'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_VERSION = '11.11.3.6-1'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_HOST = '172.28.0.12'
#     NVIDIA_PRODUCT_NAME = 'CUDA'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_DEV_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-dev-11-8'
#     USE_AUTH_EPHEM = '1'
#     NV_CUDA_CUDART_VERSION = '11.8.89-1'
#     HOME = '/root'
#     LANG = 'en_US.UTF-8'
#     CUDA_VERSION = '11.8.0'
#     CLOUDSDK_CONFIG = '/content/.config'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE = 'libcublas-11-8=11.11.3.6-1'
#     COLAB_RELEASE_TAG = 'release-colab-20230302-060133-RC02'
#     KMP_TARGET_PORT = '9000'
#     CLICOLOR = '1'
#     KMP_EXTRA_ARGS = ('--listen_host=172.28.0.12 --target_host=172.28.0.12 '
 '--tunnel_background_save_url=https://colab.research.google.com/tun/m/cc48301118ce562b961b3c22d803539adc1e0c19/m-s-36idqq70cigpp '
 '--tunnel_background_save_delay=10s '
 '--tunnel_periodic_background_save_frequency=30m0s '
 '--enable_output_coalescing=true --output_coalescing_required=true')
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_PACKAGE = 'libnpp-dev-11-8=11.8.0.86-1'
#     NV_LIBCUBLAS_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libcublas-11-8'
#     COLAB_KERNEL_MANAGER_PROXY_PORT = '6000'
#     CLOUDSDK_PYTHON = 'python3'
#     NV_LIBNPP_DEV_VERSION = '11.8.0.86-1'
#     ENABLE_DIRECTORYPREFETCHER = '1'
#     NO_GCE_CHECK = 'False'
#     JPY_PARENT_PID = '83'
#     PYTHONPATH = '/env/python'
#     TERM = 'xterm-color'
#     NV_LIBCUSPARSE_DEV_VERSION = '11.7.5.86-1'
#     GIT_PAGER = 'cat'
#     LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/cuda/lib64/stubs'
#     NV_CUDNN_VERSION = '8.7.0.84'
#     SHLVL = '0'
#     PAGER = 'cat'
#     NV_CUDA_LIB_VERSION = '11.8.0-1'
#     NVARCH = 'x86_64'
#     NV_CUDNN_PACKAGE_DEV = 'libcudnn8-dev=8.7.0.84-1+cuda11.8'
#     NV_CUDA_COMPAT_PACKAGE = 'cuda-compat-11-8'
#     MPLBACKEND = 'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE = 'libnccl2=2.16.2-1+cuda11.8'
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = '/usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64'
#     COLAB_GPU = ''
#     GCS_READ_CACHE_BLOCK_SIZE_MB = '16'
#     NV_NVPROF_VERSION = '11.8.87-1'
#     PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/opt/bin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/tools/node/bin:/tools/google-cloud-sdk/bin'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_NAME = 'libnccl2'
#     COLAB_DEBUG_ADAPTER_MUX_PATH = '/usr/local/bin/dap_multiplexer'
#     NV_LIBNCCL_PACKAGE_VERSION = '2.16.2-1'
#     PYTHONWARNINGS = 'ignore:::pip._internal.cli.base_command'
#     DEBIAN_FRONTEND = 'noninteractive'
#     COLAB_BACKEND_VERSION = 'next'
#     OLDPWD = '/'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/root/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/root/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

my requirements in my .spec are `requirements = python3,kivy, paho-mqtt, opencv-python, pyaudio`

Comment: You will need a recipe for pyaudio which currently does not exist, I am in the same boat as you, i'll let you know if I find any solution